# Product Category in navigation menu in sitefinity 7

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sitefinity

How can I use product category in my navigation menus?

My category Str is:

```
Category 1
  Sub Category 11
        Product 1
        Product 2
        Product 3
  Sub Category 12
        Product 1
        Product 2
        Product 3
Category 2
  Sub Category 21
        Product 1
        Product 2
        Product 3
  Sub Category 22
        Product 1
        Product 2
        Product 3
Category 3
  Sub Category 31
        Product 1
        Product 2
        Product 3
  Sub Category 32
        Product 1
        Product 2
        Product 3
```

I want top navigation as my category and sub category in navigation dropdown. Can you Provide me the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this and I'm assuming you're using Departments if you're referring to Sitefnity Ecommerce but let me know if I'm wrong.

- If you use Ecommerce Departments you have access to a more robust
  widget then Categories and while these cant be intermingled with
  Sitefinity Pages and thus the Navigation widget it might be a good
  option.
- If your products run off one list page and are in departments you can
  create redirecting pages under Pages and have them point to the
  corresponding department so something like
  ~/products/-in-department/departments/top-level, this will then allow
  you to use a navigation control that mirrors your departments /
  categories.
- The last option is to create individual pages for each category and
  then when you add your product list widget to each page, filter it by
  a specific department.

Comment: Thanks For The Solution i have tried the 3rd option